# sql - find amounts that end in 999

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to find amounts that end in 999. What I have so far is:

```
select * 
from bkpf_bseg_0010
where right(cast(dmbtr as int),3) = 999
```

But when I run the query I get the following error message:

> Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 4302564925.000000

The column `dmbtr` is a float. Any other ideas on how to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get a number overflow when casting big numbers to `int` which has only a limited range. `bigint` should be enough.

```
where cast(dmbtr as bigint) % 1000 = 999
```

And you can also use modulo to get the last 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from bkpf_bseg_0010 where right(cast(dmbtr as bigint),3) = 999
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is your values in column has larger size to handle in INT datatype. Use different datatype to handle those values instead of INT

```
right(cast(dmbtr as bigint),3) = 999
```